# Avoid Sprites from spawing on top of each other

Tags: javascript, image

I made like 6 sprites in my code and i spawn them randomly in the canvas but sometimes the sprites spawn right on top of each other.

Here is all my code where i drew my cars in the canvas:

```
//Setting the canvas and context
var canvas = document.getElementById('background');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

//================
// CAR Class
//================

//Uploading obstacle car
var carImage = new Image();
carImage.src = "img/Car.png";

function Car(x, y, speed, mod, angle) {
    this.x = x; // x center of car
    this.y = y; // y center of car
    this.speed = speed;
    this.mod = mod;
    this.angle = angle;

    this.move = function () {
        this.x += (this.speed * this.mod) * Math.cos(Math.PI / 180 * this.angle);
        this.y += (this.speed * this.mod) * Math.sin(Math.PI / 180 * this.angle);
        if (this.y > context.canvas.height + 150) {
            this.y = -carImage.height;
            this.x = Math.floor(Math.random() * (canvas.width));
        }
    };

    this.draw = function () {
        context.save();
        context.translate(this.x, this.y);
        context.rotate(this.angle* Math.PI / 180);
        context.drawImage(carImage, -(carImage.width / 2), -(carImage.height / 2));
        context.restore();

        if (this.x > context.canvas.width){
        context.beginPath();
        context.fillStyle = "red";
        context.font = "50px Verdana"
        context.fillText("Out of bounds! Get Back!", 100, 100);
        }

        if (this.x < 0){
        context.beginPath();
        context.fillStyle = "red";
        context.font = "50px Verdana"
        context.fillText("Out of bounds! Get Back!", 100, 100);
        }
    };

  this.testCollision = function(other) {
    dx = (Math.abs(other.x - this.x))
    dy = (Math.abs(other.y - this.y))
    da = (carImage.width / 2)
    db = (carImage.height)
    if (dx < da && dy < db) {
        this.mod = 0;
    }
   };
}

//================
//ENTER: USER CAR
//================
var userCar  = new Car(450, 730, 20, -1, -90);
setupKeys(userCar);

//=====================
//ENTER: OBSTACLE CARS
//=====================

var obstacleCar1;
var obstacleCar2;
var obstacleCar3;
var obstacleCar4;
var obstacleCar5;
var obstacleCar6;
// ================
//Starting game
// ================

function setupGame () {
  obstacleCar1 = new Car(150, 10, 5, 2.9, 90);
  obstacleCar2 = new Car(300, 10, 5, 2.9, 90);
  obstacleCar3 = new Car(450, 10, 5, 2.9, 90);
  obstacleCar4 = new Car(600, 10, 5, 2.9, 90);
  obstacleCar5 = new Car(750, 10, 5, 2.9, 90);
  obstacleCar6 = new Car(900, 10, 5, 2.9, 90);
  gameOver = false;
  startTime = Date.now();
  score = 0;
}

//=========================
//Properties for score keep
//=========================
var score;
var startTime;
var gameOver;
var spaceBarPressed = false;

//=========================
// Launch the game
//=========================
setupGame();
var gameLoopInterval = setInterval(gameLoop, 30);

//===========================
//Draw Final and Elasped Time
//===========================
function drawElapsedTime() {
    context.save();
    context.fillStyle = "black";
    context.font = "30px Verdana";
    context.fillText(parseInt((Date.now() - startTime) / 1000) + " secs", canvas.width - 110, 40);
    context.restore();
}

function drawFinalScore() {
    context.save();
    context.fillStyle = "black";
    context.font = "30px Verdana";
    context.fillText("Game Over: " + score + " secs", 368, 100);
    context.font = "12px Verdana";
    context.fillText("Press space to restart", 450, 150);
    context.restore();
}

//========================
//All game draw properties
//========================

function gameLoop() {
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    if (gameOver) {
      drawFinalScore();
      if (spaceBarPressed) {
         setupGame ();
      }
      return;
    }

obstacleCar1.move();
obstacleCar1.draw();
obstacleCar1.testCollision(userCar);


//Spawn obstacle cars at different times

if (parseInt((Date.now() - startTime) / 1000) >= 3){
    obstacleCar2.move();
    obstacleCar2.testCollision(userCar);
    obstacleCar2.draw();
}

if (parseInt((Date.now() - startTime) / 1000) >= 5){ 
    obstacleCar3.move();
    obstacleCar3.testCollision(userCar);
    obstacleCar3.draw();
}

if (parseInt((Date.now() - startTime) / 1000) >= 7){ 
    obstacleCar4.move();
    obstacleCar4.testCollision(userCar);
    obstacleCar4.draw();
}

if (parseInt((Date.now() - startTime) / 1000) >= 10){ 
    obstacleCar5.move();
    obstacleCar5.testCollision(userCar);
    obstacleCar5.draw();
}

if (parseInt((Date.now() - startTime) / 1000) >= 13){ 
    obstacleCar6.move();
    obstacleCar6.testCollision(userCar);
    obstacleCar6.draw();
}

//ULTIMATE MODE increase speed for all cars
if (parseInt((Date.now() - startTime) / 1000) >= 15){

    obstacleCar1.speed = 9;
    obstacleCar2.speed = 9;
    obstacleCar3.speed = 9;
    obstacleCar4.speed = 9;
    obstacleCar5.speed = 9;
    obstacleCar6.speed = 9;
}

//Display ULTIMATE MODE When it starts
if (parseInt((Date.now() - startTime) / 1000) >= 15 && parseInt((Date.now() - startTime) / 1000) <= 19){
    context.beginPath();
    context.fillStyle = "red";
    context.font = "50px Verdana"
    context.fillText("ULTIMATE MODE!", 100, 100);
}

    if (obstacleCar1.mod === 0) {
       score = parseInt((Date.now() - startTime) / 1000);
       gameOver = true;
       spaceBarPressed = false;
    }

    if (obstacleCar2.mod === 0) {
       score = parseInt((Date.now() - startTime) / 1000);
       gameOver = true;
       spaceBarPressed = false;
    }
    if (obstacleCar3.mod === 0) {
       score = parseInt((Date.now() - startTime) / 1000);
       gameOver = true;
       spaceBarPressed = false;
    }
    if (obstacleCar4.mod === 0) {
       score = parseInt((Date.now() - startTime) / 1000);
       gameOver = true;
       spaceBarPressed = false;
    }

    if (obstacleCar5.mod === 0) {
       score = parseInt((Date.now() - startTime) / 1000);
       gameOver = true;
       spaceBarPressed = false;
    }
    if (obstacleCar6.mod === 0) {
       score = parseInt((Date.now() - startTime) / 1000);
       gameOver = true;
       spaceBarPressed = false;
    }

    userCar.draw();

    drawElapsedTime();
}

//=========================
// BORDERS
//=========================

function borderCar() {

    if (this.x > context.canvas.width){
        context.beginPath();
        context.fillStyle = "red";
        context.font = "50px Verdana"
        context.fillText("Out of bounds! Get Back!", 100, 100);
    }
};


function borderCar2() {

    if (this.x < 0){
        context.beginPath();
        context.fillStyle = "red";
        context.font = "50px Verdana"
        context.fillText("Out of bounds! Get Back!", 100, 100);
    }
};

//========================
//  Keys handling
//========================

function setupKeys(target) {
    var cancelledKeys = [32, 37, 38, 39, 40];

    function keyUpHandler(event) {
        if (event.keyCode == 38 || event.keyCode == 40) {
            mod = 0;
        }
    }

    function keyDownHandler(event) {
        var keyCode = event.keyCode;
        if (keyCode == 37) {
            target.x -= target.speed;
        }
        if (keyCode == 39) {
            target.x += target.speed;
        }
              if (keyCode == 32) {
           spaceBarPressed =  true;
        }


        // space and arrow keys
        if (cancelledKeys.indexOf(keyCode) > -1) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    }

    //Event listeners for keys
    window.addEventListener("keydown", keyDownHandler, false);
    window.addEventListener("keyup", keyUpHandler, false);
}
```

In the comment "Enter obstacles cars" is where i am spawning all of my obstacle cars.

If you prefer a fiddle, its right [here](http://jsbin.com/jipepigida/2/edit)

Answer (score 1):

I apologize I know you didn't ask for me to do this. But before I continue I have rewritten your current JavaScript, please tell me if you don't understand anything. One thing you have to do is change your canvas id to: ***canvas***

```
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var carImage = new Image();

carImage.src = 'http://images.clipartpanda.com/car-top-view-clipart-red-racing-car-top-view-fe3a.png';

function Car(x, y, speed, mod, angle){
    this.x     = x;
    this.y     = y || 10;
    this.speed = speed || 5;
    this.mod   = mod || 2.9;
    this.angle = angle || 90;
}

Car.prototype = {
    move: function(){
        this.x += (this.speed * this.mod) * Math.cos(Math.PI / 180 * this.angle);
        this.y += (this.speed * this.mod) * Math.sin(Math.PI / 180 * this.angle);
        if (this.y > context.canvas.height + 150) {
            this.y = -carImage.height;
            this.x = Math.floor(Math.random() * (canvas.width));
        }
    },
    draw: function(){
        context.save();
        context.translate(this.x, this.y);
        context.rotate(this.angle* Math.PI / 180);
        context.drawImage(carImage, -(carImage.width / 2), -(carImage.height / 2));
        context.restore();

        if (this.x > context.canvas.width){
            context.beginPath();
            context.fillStyle = "red";
            context.font = "50px Verdana";
            context.fillText("Out of bounds! Get Back!", 100, 100);
        }

        if (this.x < 0){
            context.beginPath();
            context.fillStyle = "red";
            context.font = "50px Verdana";
            context.fillText("Out of bounds! Get Back!", 100, 100);
        }
    },
    testCollision: function(other){
        var dx = (Math.abs(other.x - this.x));
        var dy = (Math.abs(other.y - this.y));
        var da = (carImage.width / 2);
        var db = (carImage.height);
        if (dx < da && dy < db) this.mod = 0;
    }
}



var game = {
    userCar: new Car(450, 730, 20, -1, -90),
    spaceBarPressed: false,
    setup: function(){
        this.obstacleCars    = [new Car(150), new Car(300), new Car(450), new Car(600), new Car(750), new Car(900)];
        this.gameOver        = false;
        this.startTime       = Date.now();
        this.score           = 0;
    },
    drawElapsedTime: function(){
        context.save();
        context.fillStyle = "black";
        context.font = "30px Verdana";
        context.fillText(parseInt((Date.now() - this.startTime) / 1000) + " secs", canvas.width - 110, 40);
        context.restore();
    },
    drawFinalScore: function(){
        context.save();
        context.fillStyle = "black";
        context.font      = "30px Verdana";
        context.fillText("Game Over: " + this.score + " secs", 368, 100);
        context.font      = "12px Verdana";
        context.fillText("Press space to restart", 450, 150);
        context.restore();
    },
    loop: function(){
        context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        if (this.gameOver) {
            this.drawFinalScore();
            if (this.spaceBarPressed) this.setup();
            return;
        }
        this.obstacleCars[0].move();
        this.obstacleCars[0].draw();
        this.obstacleCars[0].testCollision(this.userCar);

        this.spawn(3, this.obstacleCars[1]);
        this.spawn(5, this.obstacleCars[2]);
        this.spawn(7, this.obstacleCars[3]);
        this.spawn(10, this.obstacleCars[4]);
        this.spawn(13, this.obstacleCars[5]);

        if(parseInt((Date.now() - this.startTime) / 1000) >= 15){
            for(var car of this.obstacleCars) car.speed = 9;
        }

        if (parseInt((Date.now() - this.startTime) / 1000) >= 15 && parseInt((Date.now() - this.startTime) / 1000) <= 19){
            context.beginPath();
            context.fillStyle = "red";
            context.font = "50px Verdana";
            context.fillText("ULTIMATE MODE!", 100, 100);
        }

        for(var car of this.obstacleCars){
            if(car.mod === 0){
                this.score = parseInt((Date.now() - this.startTime) / 1000);
                this.gameOver = true;
                this.spaceBarPressed = false;
            }
        }

        this.userCar.draw();

        this.drawElapsedTime();
        requestAnimationFrame(this.loop.bind(this));
    },
    spawn: function(num, car){
        if(parseInt((Date.now() - this.startTime) / 1000) >= num){
            car.move();
            car.testCollision(this.userCar);
            car.draw();
        }
    }
}

setupKeys(game.userCar);
game.setup();
game.loop();

function setupKeys(target){
    var cancelledKeys = [32, 37, 38, 39, 40];

    window.addEventListener('keydown', function(event){
        var keyCode = event.keyCode;
        if (keyCode == 37) {
            target.x -= target.speed;
        } else if(keyCode == 39){
            target.x += target.speed;
        } else if(keyCode == 32){
            game.spaceBarPressed = true;
        }

        if (~cancelledKeys.indexOf(keyCode)) event.preventDefault();
    });
    window.addEventListener('keyup', function(event){
        if(event.keyCode == 38 || event.keyCode == 40) game.userCar.mod = 0;
    });
}
```

Comment: Cool but could you tell me specifically where the code is for avoiding the obstacles to spawn on top of each other.

Comment: I've only done two object checking if they spawn in the same place but you have multiple cars being spawned. So some way some how in the spawn method. Save the positions to an array and then generate an x and y value and check if it exist in the array